# how to convert/calculate \$\text{kJ}/\text{m}^2\$ to \$\text{W}/\text{m}^2\$

Tags: solar-energy, watts, conversion

I have some solar radiation data that comes in \$\text{kJ}/\text{m}^2\$. These data were formerly available for download in \$\text{W}/\text{m}^2\$. I tried to find some ways to do the conversion from \$\text{kJ}/\text{m}^2\$ to \$\text{W}/\text{m}^2\$, but without success.

Is this conversion possible?

Comment: No, these are different dimensions.

Comment: Joules are energy units, watts are power units. Give us some context and we may be able to help.

Comment: Let's suppose I want to know the monthly average of horizontal global irradiation of the city I live in. Taking the data from this site that gives me the hourly irradiation in kJ/m2, how would this be done if I needed the average to be in w/m2.day?

Comment: @Dexter77 If you are provided with Joules per meter squared, then just divide by the number of seconds over which those numbers were integrated. If it is a monthly figure, then divide by the number of seconds in a month. Etc.

Comment: @Hearth, oops, inversion error.

Answer (score 1):

If your irradiance data is per hour, then these are the units:

$$\frac{kJ}{hm^2}$$

A joule is a watt-second, k is 1000, there are 3600 seconds in an hour:

$$=\frac{1000Ws}{m^2h(3600s/h)}$$

Cancelling units:

$$\frac{kJ}{hm^2}=\frac{0.2777W}{m^2}$$

Or

$$\frac{3.6kJ}{hm^2}=\frac{W}{m^2}$$

Comment: Or use this: https://www.unitconverters.net/power/kilojoule-hour-to-watt.htm

Comment: ok. So, If I have at 09:00 UTC 186.3 kJ/h, the calculation would be?

`1 kJ/h = 0.2777777778 W
186.3 kJ/h x 0.2777777778 W = **51.750000004 w/h**`

If I wanted this per month would I use the 0.2777777778 x 30? 

Does the "m^2" make any difference in the calculation or does it only means that the incidence was per square meter?

Comment: 186.3 kJ/(hm^2) = 51.75 W/m^2. These are units of *power* per square meter, they are independent of time. You can calculate the *energy* by multiplying by the appropriate unit of time. If you want the *energy* per month, then multiply the kJ/(hm^2) by 24 hours per day times 30 days per month. Then the units are kJ/m^2.

Comment: Since the m^2 is in both denominators, the same conversion works.

Comment: Note that although these conversions are correct, they are out of context. They assume constant irradiance, which is not true.

Comment: what variant/error we can define for a constant irradiance? Does it have a math formula?

Answer (score 0):

One watt for one second is one Joule.

Irradiance in W/m2 is about peak power when the sun shines at optimum angle. Combined with solar panel efficiency, this will tell you the maximum power your solar panels can output, so you may design the rest of the system to be able to use that power. But it won't tell you how much energy you get in a day.

Energy is measured in kJ/m2 over a unit of time, for example a day or a year. This will tell you how much energy your solar panel will actually produce during a day or during a year. The number is proportional to peak power at that latitude, but takes other things into account, for example seasonality, weather, and the fact that the sun doesn't shine 24/7. So, energy measured in kJ/m2 over a year depends on latitude, average weather in that specific location, etc.

There is no way to convert directly between these two figures unless you also know the exact location and have accurate statistics about it, which usually involves tables of actual measured solar output.